# How can I remove all white spaces?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following:

```
var xpto = "AB23. 3434-.34212 23 42."
```

I'm removing the "." "-" And ""

```
xpto.replace(/\./g,"").replace(/\-/g,"").replace("/\s/g","")
```

How can I remove all white spaces?

Comment: the regex for whitespace is `\s`

Comment: `replace("/\s/g","")` =/= `replace(/\s/g,"")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last `replace` is using a string, not a regular expression. You also don't seem to have kept the result:

```
xpto = xpto.replace(/\./g,"").replace(/\-/g,"").replace(/\s/g,"");
//   ^    No quotes here -------------------------------^--^
//   \--- Remember result
```

You can also shorten that and just call `replace` once, using a character class (`[...]`):

```
xpto = xpto.replace(/[-.\s]/g,"");
```

(Note that when using the `-` character *literally* in a character class, you must make it the first character after the opening `[` or the last character before the closing `]`, or put a backslash in front of it. If it appears between two other characters (`[a-z]`, for instance), it means "any character in the range".)

Comment: `.` does not need escaping in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove white spaces using `replace` function

```
xpto.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from the quotes around your last regex, however I might also point out that you are calling `replace` way more than needed:

```
xpto = xpto.replace(/[\s.-]/g,"");
```

This will strip out spaces, dots and hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

You done it right, but forgot the quotation marks `""` at `/\s/g`. Also, you want to change the string xpto, to the replaced xpto, so you can now do something with it.

**Javascript**

```
var xpto = "AB23. 3434-.34212 23 42."
xpto = xpto.replace(/\./g,"").replace(/\-/g,"").replace(/\s/g,"");
```

**Output**

`AB233434342122342`

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24tQG/)